# Как в Flask отключить логирование HTTP запросов?

Tags: python, flask

Хочется из консоли убрать такого вида логи:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/May/2015 15:09:56] "GET /tips HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/May/2015 15:09:56] "GET /vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/May/2015 15:09:56] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Уточните:чему равны your_flask_instance.DEBUG и your_flask_instance.TESTING

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
app.logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

Можно создать новый handler, и перенаправить все логи в файл. Смотрите модуль [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html)

Для того, чтобы отключить логирование http запросов:

```
log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug') 
log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Comment: Требуется отключить лишь логирование http запросов. Я пользуюсь app.logger для своих логов.